# Laravel Stripe Error: No such token: tok_###

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments

I'm following a tutorial on how to make an e-commerce website with Laravel, and I'm using the Github Cartalyst package to implement Stripe, but when processing the payment with Stripe, everything works fine in the tutorial, but I get the following error:

[image]

I was searching the internet and I cannot find a solution.

I followed the steps specifically (as indicated in the tutorial), but I think it's a separate problem.

My version of Laravel is 5.6 and PHP 7.2.

Can someone help me?

The link to the video tutorial is below in case you need it.

The process I'm following is in the 20th minute:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fgsI5jyPSAY&t=883s

Comment: This error almost always means that you are creating the token with one key from one account and trying to use it with a different key from a different account. You would have to triple check the API keys in your code to make sure you use the right ones

Comment: and in what way could you solve it?

Comment: can you please share your code what you have tried so far ?

Comment: To solve it, you simply check your code for the API keys you use and use the exact keys for your account which is not the case right now as the token is created on the wrong account

Comment: Hello! I solved the problem. There is a JavaScript code that is copied from the Stripe documentation which has a token, that token I had was different from the one I was using in the .env file, then I modified that token and it worked correctly.

Thank you very much!